# Python os.system() not found

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Trying to run a file starting Raspberry Pi camera.
I can easily do it with

> cd dir

and then

> ./start.sh

So i'm trying to run it in Python code:

```
os.system("~/RosPi_Cam_Web_Interface/start.sh")
```

But it says this dir is not found.
What am i doing wrong?
And how would be better to do it with subprocess?

Answer (score 4):

The `~` is expanded by the shell. You have to call `os.path.expanduser` to expand it to the home directory:

```
import os.path
import system

os.system(os.path.expanduser("~/RosPi_Cam_Web_Interface/start.sh"))
```

Comment: weird..When i execute your advise in shell, it runs well. But when i execute it in Python:                                                                          `class CameraOffHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
 @gen.coroutine
 def get(self):
  os.system(os.path.expanduser("~/RosPi_Cam_Web_Interface/start.sh"))`   i still get not found error